# Is it possible to use SwiftUI Modifier to change particular element in content?

Tags: swift, swiftui

There is a [good article](https://mecid.github.io/2019/08/28/composable-styling-in-swiftui/) regarding how to use SwiftUI Modifier to change the appearance. But this will change the appearance globally. That means it changes the style of everything. I'm wondering if there is a way to use similar method to only change the specific elements in content? For example, I have a component **MyComponent** which includes a **Text** and a **Button**. I want to change the style of **Text** and **Button** separately.

```
MyComponent.myTextStyle(...).myButtonStyle(...)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can apply modifier to instance of a view like this :

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View { 
        Text("My text").modifier(PrimaryLabelStyle())
    }
}
```

You can also have a component and apply external modifier to the component.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        MyComponent(textModifier: PrimaryLabelStyle(), buttonModifier: PrimaryButtonStyle())        
    }
}

struct MyComponent<T,U>: View where T:ViewModifier, U:ViewModifier{
    let textModifier:T
    let buttonModifier:U
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("My Text")
                .modifier(textModifier)
            Button(action:{}){
                Text("My Button")
            }.modifier(buttonModifier)
        }

    }
}

struct PrimaryLabelStyle: ViewModifier {
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .padding()
            .background(Color.red)
            .foregroundColor(Color.white)
            .font(.largeTitle)
    }
}

struct PrimaryButtonStyle: ViewModifier {
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .padding()
            .background(Color.yellow)
            .foregroundColor(Color.white)
            .font(.largeTitle)
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This is not what I want. The reason I tried to use the modifier is trying to simplify the constructor of a component. If I can pass the modifier as a parameter to constructor then I'm also possible to pass some configuration values.